# Data Source Permissions in the User Console

Tags: pentaho

I would like to make the user console available to our users, but I cannot do to if I can't set permissions on individual data sources. That is to say, user A would only have access to use data source A, and user B would only have access to use data source B.

**Is it possible to restrict a user or role to a subset of defined datasources?**

Answer (score 2):

try this for every datasource: http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/schema.php#Access_control

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the Mondrian One-To-One UserRoleMapper is uncommented in the /pentaho-solutions/system/pentahoObjects.spring.xml file.
It will look like this:
https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.1/0N0/020/080/010/000